# Spring MVC Controller RequestMapping method not recognized

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlet-3.0

I have defined 2 methods in controller class . When I comment out the second method(displayHomePage), I can access the login page, but when I un-comment the second method none of the return(login.jsp or home.jsp) works. It gives HTTP 404 resource not found error. Below is my web.xml, dispatcher.xml and controller class.

Where am I going wrong? Also, if i remove "method=RequestMethod.GET" for both methods, I can access both pages without issues. It's confusing. Please help me out.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
   <display-name>demo</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>demo-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>demo-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>
         org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
      </listener-class>
   </listener>
   <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>
          /WEB-INF/demo-dispatcher-servlet.xml
       </param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

demo-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">


   <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.demo.controller" />
   <context:annotation-config />

   <bean
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix">
         <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
      </property>
      <property name="suffix">
         <value>.jsp</value>
      </property>
   </bean>

   <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
   <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
</beans>
```

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(name="/login" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayLoginPage(){
        return "login";
    }

/*  @RequestMapping(name="/home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayHomePage(){
        return "home";
    }*/
}
```

and just login.jsp and home.jsp pages under WEB-INF/jsp folder

Comment: When starting the application, spring should log all the mappings like this
`Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String x.x.x.controller.LoginController.displayLoginPage()`
Can you see anything similar in your logs?

Comment: Yes log is :SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'loginController' method public java.lang.String com.abc.demo.controller.LoginController.displayHomePage()
to {[],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'loginController' bean method
public java.lang.String com.ab.demo.controller.LoginController.displayLoginPage() mapped.

Comment: doesn't this desc helps you?

There is already 'loginController' bean method public java.lang.String com.ab.demo.controller.LoginController.displayLoginPage() mapped.

Comment: Not really, so, i want 'loginController' bean mapped to both methods, not just one method. Am I missing something?

Comment: Finally got it working. I just replace 'name' with 'value' in RequestMapping. Thanks for the responses.